# Why am I receiving the PSL-00103 Error in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, pls-00103, ora-00984

I am trying to make a procedure that would insert a row into a table in Oracle SQL. However, I can't figure out a solid reason on why this issue exists when I write any type of procedure.

I have tried changing the syntax around a couple of times, but I still don't know how to remedy the issue.

Errors given:

> Error at line 1: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following: in out   table ... columns long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar
> Error at line 5: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error at line 6: PL/SQL: ORA-00984: column not allowed here

Code:

```
create or replace procedure insert_category(
    category_name_param in categories.category_name%type)
as
begin
    insert into categories (category_id, category_name)
    values (category_id, category_name_param);
end;
```

Comment: This cant' be right in your context `values (category_id, category_name_param);`
where is this defined ? - `category_id`

Comment: @T.S. It's not exactly defined in the procedure, if that's what you mean. I only simply put `category_id` as I felt the need to follow the statement rules. I'm not very confident in my ability to write SQL.

Comment: I assume that the ID is issued automatically (from a sequence with a trigger or identity column). In that case just: `insert into categories (category_name) values (category_name_param);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that procedure lacks in yet another parameter; see if this helps (I *presumed* that such a column exists in the table; can't be sure as you didn't post table description):

```
create or replace procedure insert_category(
    category_name_param in categories.category_name%type,
    category_id_param   in categories.category_id%type      --> this
   )
as
begin
    insert into categories 
      (category_id, 
       category_name)
    values 
      (category_id_param,                                   --> this 
       category_name_param);
end;
```